# Configuration doesn't match the required schema: Data path "/lib" must NOT have additional properties (umdModuleIds)

Tags: angular, angularbuild

When I run `ng build` I get,

```
❯ ng build
Building Angular Package
Configuration doesn't match the required schema.
Data path "/lib" must NOT have additional properties (umdModuleIds).
```

What is the source of this problem and how can I resolve it

Comment: Hi! Could you solve this? I have the same problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as is that in [version 13.0.0 of `ng-packager` a BREAKING CHANGE was introduced](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2018-02-05)

> We no longer generate UMD bundles. The below options which were used for UMD bundle generation has also been removed;
>
> - `umdModuleIds`
> - `amdId`
> - `umdId`

[According to the comments in this thread these options have not been in use since version 2.](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1364#issuecomment-517456454) but now they generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just removing `umdModuleIds` from `ng-package.json` solved for me